# Symfony2 - Doctrine returns big unexcepted object

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I use Symfony2 and Doctrine in my project. I would like get some data from database. So I create simple code in my controller

```
$repository = $this->getDoctrine()
                ->getRepository('AppBundle:TransactionDefined');


$defined = $repository->findOneBy(
    array(
      'description' => $transaction->getDescription(),
      'recipient' => $transaction->getRecipient(),
      'accountNumber' => $transaction->getAccountNumber(),
      'title' => $transaction->getClearTitle()
    )
);
```

In my opinion I should get TransactionDefined object

But I got big object with strange data. What is wrong in my code ?

```
object(AppBundle\Entity\TransactionDefined)#645 (6) {


["category":protected]=>
  object(Proxies\__CG__\AppBundle\Entity\TransactionCategory)#656 (6) {
    ["__initializer__"]=>
    object(Closure)#648 (3) {
      ["static"]=>
      array(2) {
        ["entityPersister"]=>
        object(Doctrine\ORM\Persisters\BasicEntityPersister)#646 (14) {
          ["class":protected]=>
          object(Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadata)#596 (37) {
            ["name"]=>
            string(36) "AppBundle\Entity\TransactionCategory"
            ["namespace"]=>
            string(16) "AppBundle\Entity"
            ["rootEntityName"]=>
            string(36) "AppBundle\Entity\TransactionCategory"
            ["customGeneratorDefinition"]=>
            NULL
            ["customRepositoryClassName"]=>
            NULL
            ["isMappedSuperclass"]=>
            bool(false)
            ["parentClasses"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["subClasses"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["namedQueries"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["namedNativeQueries"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
            ["sqlResultSetMappings"]=>
            array(0) {
            }
```

....

I paste only part od this object, because it is very huge

Comment: The ORM bloat was the reason I dumped the framework. I have seen proxies sometimes 100MB per user. Dumping them mostly crashes the browser.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there's nothing wrong with your code. That object is just a Proxy Object used by Doctrine to lazy load the real entity object.

http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/advanced-configuration.html#proxy-objects

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($defined)` instead of var_dump. `Debug::dump()` will only get you the entity fields, and allows you to control how deep you want to follow entity relations (defaults to 2 levels).  var_dump will also cause a fatal error if you have any bi-directional relations, because it will keep going back and forth between the related entities.